# Using Custom ElasticSearch Analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a question regarding elastic search analyzers.
I create a custom analyzer like this:

```
Analyzers(o => o.Custom("custom", 
                        m => m.CharFilters("icu_normalizer").Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding").Tokenizer("icu_tokenizer")
```

And tried the analyzer which results in the following token (good):

```
/_analyze?analyzer=custom&text=SödertorG

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "sodertorg",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try to search for this token, like this:

```
_search?q=sodertorg&analyzer=custom
```

I don't get any results (bad).

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?
Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use the exact field in which you have stored the data, i.e. `_search?q=field:sodertorg&analyzer=custom` ?

Comment: doesn't help. The standard analyzer will find the result as soon as I search for 'södertorg' (or _search?q=name1:södertorg), but my custom analyzer doesn't work altough it works for other searches (for example 'jarn' as part of the email field)

Comment: where is your custom analyzer stored?

Answer (score 0):

When performing a `query_string` query as you're doing, you'll be targeting the `_all` field. The `analyzer` specified in the query string applies only to how the query is analyzed; the `_all` field will still be using the `standard` analyzer when content is being indexed.

To fix, you'll need to ensure that your custom `analyzer` is applied to the `_all` field in the mapping e.g.

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("my-index", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(o => o
                .Custom("custom", m => m
                    .CharFilters("icu_normalizer")
                    .Filters("lowercase", "asciifolding")
                    .Tokenizer("icu_tokenizer")
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Project>(mm => mm
            // apply to _all field
            .AllField(s => s
                .Analyzer("custom")
            )
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

With the analyzer applied in this way in the mapping, you should get the expected results; You won't need to specify the analyzer in the query anymore as the analyzer in the mapping will be used for both index time and query time analysis.